# Want older 32 bit version for Lotus, Wordperfect and corel photo program.

Tags: ibm-lotus-notes

I have had the new version of Ubuntu installed, but it does not want to run my older non-MS products.  The sole purposes I have in owning Ubuntu are to:  Be free of MS and to keep operating my system with these functional and well known programs, Lotus and Wordperfect.  What program version can I use?  And I care not one wit about 64 bit operating.  Just give me my old stuff on an older operable computer that runs my printer.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally off-topic, but depending how old those versions of WordPerfect and Lotus 1-2-3 are, you might need [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/)...

Comment: DOSbox maybe? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and follow [this](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/IBM-lotus-notes-9.0.1-debian-7.5-64-bit-wheezy) page to install Lotus Notes 9.0.1 on your system.

For Corel WordPerfect 8.1 you could try to follow [this](http://www.wpuniverse.com/vb/showthread.php?31688-WordPerfect-8.1-for-Linux-Installation-steps-for-Ubuntu-10.04) post.

If are able to provide further information on your setup (e.g. what printer are you talking about, the versions of the program you have available) that might be helpful.

(I have not tried any of those guides. Be careful, as usual.)